# URL on Windows 2003 Server via shortened name?

Tags: url, friendly-url

I'm a developer so please excuse my ignorance on how to do this: I have access to a Windows 2003 Server where I have some web applications deployed. Instead of users accessing the web applications via some long URLs, how can I shorted the root URL of the server that more human-readable and accessible?

For example, instead of this: http://tdw2.fmwe3.server123.tpd2dss.com/MyApplication, I would like users to type something like this: http: //FinanceWeb/MyApplication.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to create a DNS entry for "FinanceWeb" that points to your other server.